# How to perform an exact search in Solr

Tags: solr

I implementing Solr search using an API. When I call it using the parameters as, "Chillout Lounge", it returns me the collection which are same/similar to the string "Chillout Lounge".
But when I search for "Chillout Lounge Box", it returns me results which don't have any of these three words.(in the DB there are values which have these 3 values, but they are not returned.)

According to me, Solr uses Fuzzy search, but when it is done it should return me some values, which will have at least one these value.

Or what could be the possible changes I should to my schema.XML, such that is would give me proper values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - "Fuzzy search" is a feature you'll have to ask for (by using `~` in standard Lucene query syntax).

If you're talking about regular searches, you can use `q.op` to select which operator to use. `q.op=AND` will make sure that all the terms match, while `q.op=OR` will make any document that contain at least one of the terms be returned. As long as you aren't using `fq` for this, the documents that match more terms should be scored higher (as the score will add up across multiple terms), and thus, be shown higher in the result set.

You can use the debug query feature in the web interface to see scores for each term for a document, and find out why the document was returned at all. If the document doesn't match *any* terms, it shouldn't be returned, unless you're asking for all documents to be returned.

Be aware that the analyzer chain defined for the field you're searching might affect what's considered a match and not.

You'll have to add a proper example to get a more detailed answer.